# Getting null when getting value from spreadsheet if special characters where used in App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not a good programmer or English speaker, sorry.

I try to access a Google spreadsheet with app script and from fixer .gs I can get the record I want but at the same time switching it to javascript the console returns "null".

This only happens when there are special characters in the fields I'm looking for, such as colon.

```js
function recullEntrades(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Dades");
  Logger.log(ws.getRange(2,1, ws.getLastRow()-1,7).getDisplayValues())
  return ws.getRange(2,1, ws.getLastRow()-1,7).getValues();
}
```

This is ok in the Logger but then,

```js
function miraEntrades(entrades) {
  console.log("entrades: " + entrades);
}

$('#vomita').click(function(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(miraEntrades).recullEntrades();
})
```

In the chrome console i get "null", this is not happening if i not use colon.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Carles! I've noticed that in the logger your are using `.getDisplayValues()`, while in the `return` statement you are using `getValues()`. Have you tried logging `.getValues()`, rather than logging `.getDisplayValues()`?

Comment: Oh! i am stupid! thx

Comment: Hey @Carles, has your issue been fixed by using `getDisplayValues` instead?

Comment: Yes!! This was my mistake.. Thanks!